# Если сущность была изменена, то поменять значение одного её столбца

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть сущность "Правила". Если пользователь изменил поле "Описание" в этой сущности, то должно автоматически меняться значение поля "Стабильность"(dropdownlist). То есть если Описание правила пришлось поменять, то оно становится нестабильным.
**Я написала триггер**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ChangeStabilityRequirement]
    ON [dbo].[Requirement]
    After UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    IF (UPDATE(Definition))     
        update [dbo].[Requirement]
        SET  Stability=2;
    END;
    go
```

Но проблема в том, что триггер срабатывает при любом изменении записи из таблицы.
Хотя я и пишу вот эту строчку: IF (UPDATE(Definition))

Comment: @Tanya: Возможно, вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос про это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Триггер вам в помощь.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как-то совсем забыла про триггер